# How to replace a target array string and change it to the user input string

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-layout

so basically I'm a new one in stackoverflow. I have this code which is replacing every underscore into user string.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String result="";
private String textresult = "The red fox jumps over the lazy dog";
EditText text;
Button btn;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button_edittext);
        final TextView tvtext = findViewById(R.id.result);
        final String les = textresult.replaceAll("[a-z]", "_");
        tvtext.setText(les);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v

    String les1 = textresult.replaceAll("[a-z]", "_");
    final String sampleText = text.getText().toString().trim();
    int noOfBtns = sampleText.length();
    int noOftext = les1.length();


    final TextView[] btns = new TextView[noOfBtns];

    for(int i=0;i<noOfBtns;i++)
    {
        btns[i] =   new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        btns[i].setText(sampleText.substring(i,i+1));

        result = result+btns[i].getText().toString();
        char[] c = result.toCharArray();

          les1 = changeCharInPosition(i, c[i], les1);*/
                tvtext.setText(les1);
        }
    }
});
}
```

so the output would be like this:

```
**T__ ___ ___ ____ ____ ___ ____ ___.**
```

the problem: so how can I target the first length of the text until the end of the text and update or replace every length of the character which is for example:

when the user input a word and update or replace:

```
**user input: the red
display: the red ___ ____ ____ ___ ____ ___.**
```

and if the user input a wrong letter for the word it will display *:

```
**user input: the red fix
display: the red f*x ____ ____ ___ ____ ___.**
```

badly needed help for this code. 
thank you!!

Comment: "how can I target the first length of the text until the end of the text and update or replace every length of the character" -- How could you replace the length of a character? What does that even mean? It seems like you need help with the string functions for your hangman game, and the Android code is completely irrelevant to the multiple, open-ended questions you're asking, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the what youre trying to do is update all those TextViews based on current userinput from the EditText. Add a TextWatcher on your `text` variable:

```
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){...
```

you have to figure out yourself what method of the TextWatcher interface you will need.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is not JavaScript, but you tagged your question as such.

So I give a simple JS answer :)

```js
const text = "The red fox jumps over the lazy dog."

const question = document.getElementById('question')
const guess = document.getElementById('guess')

// handling input
const check = (g, t) => {
  const gArr = [...g]
  const tArr = [...t]

  const r = []

  tArr.forEach((e, i) => {
    // if the character in the text is ' ' or '.'
    // just return it as it is
    if (e === ' ' || e === '.') {
      r.push(e)
    } else if (!gArr[i]) {
      // if the quess is shorter than the real text, then
      // return _ in not yet quessed places
      r.push('_')
    } else if (gArr[i]) {
      if (gArr[i] === e) {
        // if the guess is correct,
        // then return the correct guess
        r.push(e)
      } else {
        // if the guess is incorrect,
        // then return '*'
        r.push('*')
      }
    }
  })
  return r.join('')
}

// set the stage
question.innerHTML = check(guess.value, text)

// react to input events
guess.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const r = check(e.target.value, text)
  question.innerHTML = r
})
```

```html
<label for="guess">Guess the text: <input id="guess" type="text"/></label>
<div id="question"></div>
```